# Использование Clang под Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio-code, clang

Можете рассказать как обстоят дела с использованием Clang под Windows (не считая того, который идет как пакет к Visual Studio)? Лучше использовать snapshot, скомпилировать вручную, или может есть ресурсы с уже скомпиленным clang'ом?

Я скачивал snapshot под Windows с сайта LLVM, но что-то с ним у меня не работал дебаггер lldb-vscode. Да и странно, что он не обнаружился автодетектом в расширении C/C++, хотя MinGW64, Cygwin64, майкрософтовский MSVC он таким образом видит даже без прописки их в PATH.

Comment: В Visual Studio можно использовать clang, не идущий в комплекте.

Comment: Ну вот о некомплектных clang'ах и речь - где лучше достать и как поставить.

Comment: А зачем вам нужен некомлектный?

Comment: Не ставить же на все устройства Visual Studio, если нужно скомпилировать и подебажить какую-нибудь мелочь. MinGW скачал, установил - и можно его вовсю пользовать

Comment: Средства сборки (т.е. msbuild + компиляторы + SDK) можно ставить сами со себе, без IDE. Там вроде как 9 clang идет.

Comment: Это не совсем то, что мне нужно - там нет дебагера, ни LLDB, ни CDB. Со snapshot'ом с сайта LLVM проблема другая - дебагер не работает с VS Code (хотя я прописывал путь к lldb-vscode.exe, и в PATH папку добавлял). Компилировать на ноуте вручную - не хотелось бы, я тогда лучше дальше с MinGW64 останусь.

Comment: Кланг под виндой обычно используют или со стандартной библиотекой от MSVC, или от GCC (MinGW). Когда я последний раз проверял, родная стандартная библиотека под виндой не работала. Поэтому либо MinGW, либо MSVC ставить придется. *"может есть ресурсы с уже скомпиленным clang"* Своя сборка кланга есть у MSYS2. Удобно как минимум тем, что по дефолту (без флажков) использует стандартную бибилиотеку MinGW (а не ругается на отсутствие MSVC, как оффициальная сборка). Плюс там же можно найти свежий MinGW.

Comment: А lldb в vscode у меня тоже не завелся, да. Пользуюсь gdb.

Comment: *"там нет дебагера"* - на счет lldb не знаю, но CDB точно есть, причем инструменты для отладки можно также ставить отдельно от всего отстального. *"Компилировать на ноуте вручную"* - зачем? используйте msbuild. Ну и раз уж ставите VS Code, то почему бы не поставить полноценную VS?

Comment: Вроде бы чтобы пользоваться CDB, как и MSVC в целом, надо каждый раз заходить в developer prompt. Visual Studio и так стоит, да и пока что выходит, пользоваться ее инструментарием напрямую - самый рациональный вариант. Просто VS Code есть на любой платформе и он везде одинаковый. И вариант со snapshot'ом под Windows, если бы там работал дебагер, был бы идеальный.